# Add MIDI to music keyboard without disrupting its functionalities

Tags: shift-register, midi

As a DIY project I would like to add MIDI capabilities to my Yamaha PSR F51 keyboard.
I've found some projects on the Internet as [this one](https://www.instructables.com/Add-MIDI-port-to-Keyboard/), but unfortunatelly in this way the keyboard would not work as a normal keyboard anymore: its output would be only MIDI. My goal is, instead, to maintain its functionalities and add a MIDI USB port.

The keyboard's motherboard has one 13 pins ribbon cable going in and one 11 pins ribbon cable going out, which seems to suggest a 13x11 scan matrix.

[image: YAMAHA YMW-830W]

Instead of using a couple of 74HC565 shift registers to send signals to probe which key is pressed, as in the projects I found, I am thinking to use some 74HC165 to poll what the Yamaha uC is doing.

Can it work? I should find out how the Yamaha MCU is scannig the keyboard. Is it something already documented somewhere?

Edit: after reading the comments I am thinking on a different solution: the new MIDI board should completely bypass the original circuitery when powered on. When powered off the keyboard should work as before. In this way I could follow the same approach of the one in instructiontables.

Can it work? How can I electrically isolate the original circuitry?

Edit2: I’ve found the service manual of a similar model and it seems that MIDI is already available via UART. I’ll give it a try with my scope.

[image: F50 schema]

Edit3: unfortunatelly I wasn't able to find where pin 54 goes. I should remove the ribbon cables from the board but I am worried about those molex connectors: they don't hold the cable well.

[image: pin zoom]

I cannot solder near the chip's pin, it's too small. I am afraid I should give up.

Edit4: finally I made it! I found an easy way to solder a wire to pin 54 on the back side of the PCB:

[image: Back side of PCB]

The gray wire is connected to pin 54 of the chip through a via, the black wire to DGND and the white one to +3.3D.

I than soldered the other end of the wires to a DIN 5 connector using a couple of resistors as described [here](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/midi-din-electrical-specification) and got the MIDI messages on my PC using a DIN to USB cable!

Comment: The keyboard is probably wired as a matrix so you would have to monitor the scanning of the rows and columns simultaneously and rather quickly. It sounds like a lot of trouble and rather risky if the keyboard is of any value. They may not be using standard logic voltages, etc.

Comment: maybe that control chip already has MIDI, but the interface circuitry is not installed on the board

Comment: http://sandsoftwaresound.net/inside-yamaha-pss-e30-remie/

Comment: As already said it's possible that the CPU on the board has the needed port for USB MIDI and even it's possible the software responds if you success to build the missing USB hardware (no idea what's missing and what's actually included, never known anyone inside Yamaha). Then it's even possible that the MIDI in the board is implemented in a Class Compliant way - no special driver is needed. But I suspect you aren't that lucky. I have several USB Midi devices which are useless without device's own MIDI driver. But nothing prevents to try. I would purchase a second hand  MIDI instrument.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Do you think that some chip's pin is used for MIDI out? Maybe pin 54 labeled "TXD UART transmit data (output)"?

Comment: I don't know what pin 54 is supposed to do, but it wouldn't be hard to find out. Just monitor the pin and see what it does. If you see serial data at 31250 baud then it's probably MIDI.